# Signup System in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I recently started coding a website with a login/signup system with php & mysql. But when i try to make the signup it give the error, that i didn't insert the username/email. I will leave the code of the signup page and the code of the "script":

Signup page:

```
<?php

require 'inner.php';

 ?>

 <?php

require 'header.php';

  ?>


<?php 

require 'main.php';

 ?>

 <div class="signup-header">
   <center>
    <h1>Signup<span>Page</span></h1>
  </center>
 </div>
<div class="form2">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Username</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form3">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Email</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form4">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Password</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form5">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="rePassword" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Repeat Password</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>


<div class="signup-btn">

  <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <button type="text" name="signup-submit">Register</button>
  </form>

</div>


 <?php

 require 'footer.php';

  ?>
```

Script Page:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["signup-submit"]))
{

  require 'dbhandler.php';

  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $password = $_POST["password"]; 
  $repeatpassword = $_POST["rePassword"];

        if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) ||empty($repeatpassword))
        {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&username=".$username."&email=".$email);
          exit();
        }elseif(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&& !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$username)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&username");
          exit();
        }elseif (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail");
          exit();
        }elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$username))
        {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidusername");
        exit();
        }
        elseif($ps !== $rp) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php/error=passwordcheck");
          exit();
        }else {
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
          $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
          if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php/error=connectionerror ");
            exit();
          }else
          {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $result_check = mysqli_stmt_num_rows();
            if ($result_check > 0) {
              header("Location: ../signup.php/error=usertaken ");
              exit();
            }else {
              $sql = "INSERT INTO user(uidUsers,    emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?)";
              $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
              if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php/error=connectionerror ");
                exit();
              }else {

                $hash_ps = password_hash($ps,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $email,$username,$hash_ps);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                header("Location: ../signup.php/signup=success");
                exit();
              }
            }
          }
        }

}

 ?>
```

It's like PHP can't find the username/mail value.

Comment: what are u trying to do. do you want to login using email address and password. or what?

Comment: Well to login i want to use Username and Password. But the problem is in the signup script. For the signup i used: Email, Username, Password,Repeat Password

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap whole form inside `<form>` element.

In your code, you have only this little part in form, so it is not sending all of the fields you need for registration:

```
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <button type="text" name="signup-submit">Register</button>
  </form>
```

So it will be something like:

```
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post"> <!-- FORM BEGINNING HERE -->

<div class="signup-header">
   <center>
    <h1>Signup<span>Page</span></h1>
  </center>
 </div>
<div class="form2">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Username</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form3">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Email</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form4">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Password</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="form5">
  <center>
  <form class="" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="rePassword" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
      <span class="content-name">Repeat Password</span>
    </label>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>


<div class="signup-btn">
    <button type="text" name="signup-submit">Register</button>
</div>

</form> <!-- FORM ENDING HERE -->
```